# Calculate sum of columns data in Excel Pivot table base on columns name

Tags: excel

I have some data in an Excel sheet, like this:

[image]

Now I want to get below result with Pivot tables:

[image]

As you can see I want to put the columns name's of the source data at the first columns of the pivot table and sum of each columns in the second one.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating a calculated field in excel pivot table based on an item in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224929/creating-a-calculated-field-in-excel-pivot-table-based-on-an-item-in-a-column)

Comment: Abhijeet I think you didn't understand me, please read the question again. It's totally different with this thread.

Comment: Pivot tables work far better with normalized data. Can you get your data into two columns: one with city name and the second with the number?

Comment: You right [Doug Glancy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy), but my customer data is like that.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new ColumnA, follow the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120), select output Table Columns B and C and pivot those. Relabel to suit.